# Arduino Uno short circuits

Tags: arduino, power-electronics

When I connect the 5V of my Arduino to the GND why does it get short circuited ? And why does the Arduino Uno doesn't really get short circuited and the Arduino Nano does get short circuited ?

Comment: Uh you just explained how it got short circuited.

Comment: Don't short things out, just don't do it, ever. Don't cross wires, check voltages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we by mistakenly connect 5v and Gnd It gets short circuited.

Lesson learned. Gnd is technically the negative side of the battery (or other power source) and 5v is the positive side of the battery. Hook the positive side of the battery to the negative side and the battery will heat up and possibly explode.

Electricity likes to flow through the path of least resistance, and by connecting 5v to ground, thats the path much of the electricity will take.

> My doubt is how and why did this happen and how this gets prevented in the Uno but not in Nano. And I heard of a ressetable fuse in the Uno.

It's possible that you have blown a fuse in Uno, and it is possible Nano doesn't have a fuse. When a fuse is blown, an open circuit is created to prevent the rest of the parts from overheating and/or malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1):

There are two short circuit protection techniques used on the Arduino Uno and only one on the Nano. They both have a similar general purpose Low Drop Out 5V Linear Regulators with short circuit protection features. This only protects the regulator and input when you short it's VOUT directly to Ground. ***It does not protect other parts of the circuit, like if you short the ATMega's GPIO.***

The Uno has an added PTC Polyfuse on the USB's power rail VUSB. It will limit the amount of current by raising it's resistance as it's heat goes up. This helps protect the USB power supply or pc port. Again, it would not prevent damage to other parts of the circuit if you short those.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical explanation for how the short circuit is prevented from doing damage is that you have a good power supply that provides that protection. Actually, if you are using a battery, all you need is a resistor in series with the power supply's plus to the load.

Comment: A resistor in series with the load is a very crude and ineffective form of protection. There's a broad variety of ⏛ devices which are designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Actually it is a very effective means - and it answers the question posed. It depends on what you are doing. He didn't say.
There are other answers that suggest that the Uno does just that.

Comment: So your logic is "since the question is crappy, any answer will do"? And speaking of Uno, there's a difference between a resistor and a polyfuse.

Comment: The protection he was talking about has to do with something like a probe slipping off one pin and touching two pins together. Depending on what the circuit is, the power supply probably has these protections to which you allude built into it. If he is using a battery, you can pretty much bet that the device to which you refer has a series resistor as its first line of defense. Again, depending upon what he is doing, that might be all that is needed. Do you know more about what he is doing?

Comment: As far as 'crappy answer', no, but it certainly does limit what one can state definitively. How does referring to the fact that a resistor will work make it a crappy answer? It depends on what he is doing.  And a polyfuse acts as a resistor until its capabilities are exceeded, right?

Comment: A typical polyfuse will have a resistance of about 1 Ohm. If you were to use a simple resistor instead, you'd have to pick a 5W one to protect a 5V load. That's why I have said it's ineffective. You seem to disagree with this, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Why is a polyfuse ok at 1 ohm while a slightly higher resistance 1/4 w or 1/8 w is ineffective? Who said anything about requiring 1 Amp of current? If you put a 100 ohm resistor in series with the load, what would happen? OK so go buy a polyfuse, this was essentially a rhetorical question and the resistor will protect just as well as a polyfuse. If short circuited - POP! You are the one doing the questioning, not me. It depends on what he is doing.

Comment: If one has a known load, a 100 ohm resistor in series will drop the voltage to zero at 50 ma. That would protect the circuit from a short due to a slipping probe. It depends on what you are doing. Is it a design parameter - probably not, it depends on what you are doing. It could be for a test setup or ... it depends on what you are doing.